# What's the relationship between streamjs and linqjs

Tags: javascript, linq, stream, relationship, sicp

After reading SICP, I recently discovered [streamjs](https://github.com/dionyziz/stream.js). The developer referenced [linqjs](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) as an alternate implementation with different syntax, but I can't make the connection. How do the methods in streamjs map to those in linqjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used either library, but, here's my initial analysis (I've read quite a bit of SICP, but not the whole thing admittedly).

`stream.js` is an implementation of a functional style data structure for a list. Many data structures in a functional language tend to be recursive, much like the `Stream` structure.  It is composed of a head element, and a `Stream` for the tail (subsequent elements). Here, lazy evaluation can be achieved by allowing the tail to be a function (i.e. infinite sequences).

Now, to answer your question, all of the functions provided by `linq.js` should be able to be defined with other common higher order functions like map, reduce, walk, fold, etc.

Sure, `stream.js` does not implement the `Any()` method from `linq.js`, but you can just do that with `reduce()`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess they are similar because they pass functions around instead of "scalar values" ,so they can do lazy evaluation ( evaluate the result at the end of the operations / on demand and not at each operation like with classic javascript data structures). I used that principle with my [pimple.js](https://github.com/Mparaiso/Pimple.js) library , which has nothing to do with stream or link but uses lazy evalutation.

Answer (score 0):

linq.js and stream.js have the following similarities:

- Use functions to implement streams as a data structure
- Use streams to implement lazy evaluation of operations

linq.js and stream.js have the following differences:

- linq.js has syntactic sugar for querying JSON
- stream.js has the ability to chain streams
- linq.js has syntactic sugar for set operations

**References**

- [LINQ in JavaScript for Real](http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2013-12-31-linq-in-javascript-for-real.html)
- [LINQ in JavaScript, ES6 Style](http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2013-09-06-linq-in-javascript-es6.html)