# Lazy event streams in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, reactive-programming

I am trying to emulate event streams from the domain of functional reactive programming in JavaScript. There are fundamentally two ways I could do this:

1. Give each event stream an array of `listeners` and allow external code to subscribe to events in the stream. I don't like this solution because it requires a lot of bookkeeping and mutable state.
2. Reify lazy evaluation and thunks in JavaScript to simulate lazy lists, allowing you to manifest event streams as a lazy list of events generated by a conventional event listener. No bookkeeping.

Clearly the second method is far more desirable. Hence I assiduously wrote a few combinators to enable lazy evaluation in JavaScript:

```
function lazy(f, a) {
    return function (k) {
        return k(apply(f, a));
    };
}

function apply(f, a) {
    return f.apply(null, a);
}
```

The `lazy` combinator takes a function and a list of arguments and returns a thunk representing the return value of the function call.

```
function eval(a) {
    return typeof a === "function" ? a(id) : a;
}

function id(a) {
    return a;
}
```

The `eval` combinator either takes a thunk, evaluates it and returns its value or else returns an eager value unchanged. It allows you to treat both lazy and eager values the same.

Next I wrote a `cons` function to create a list:

```
function cons(head, tail) {
    return {
        head: head,
        tail: tail
    };
}
```

Then I wrote a few utility functions to put lazy evaluation to the test:

```
function fib(a, b) {
    var c = a + b;
    return cons(c, lazy(fib, [b, c]));
}

function take(n, xs) {
    return xs && n > 0 ?
        cons(xs.head, lazy(take, [n - 1, eval(xs.tail)])) :
    null;
}

function toArray(xs) {
    return xs ?
        [xs.head].concat(toArray(eval(xs.tail))) :
    [];
}
```

Finally I got the first 10 Fibonacci numbers lazily as follows:

```
var xs = take(10, fib(-1, 1));

alert(JSON.stringify(toArray(xs))); // [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
```

It worked like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/Kc5P2/

So now I am attempting to create an event stream constructor in JavaScript using lazy lists. However because events are generated asynchronously I surmise that I would need to convert all my functions into continuation passing style.

The crux of the problem is that there's no way to defer the evaluation of a thunk if the value of the thunk is not yet available. The solution is to create an asynchronous `eval` function as follows:

```
function asyncEval(a, k) {
    typeof a === "function" ? a(k) : k(a);
}
```

Now you can return an asynchronous thunk from the event stream constructor as follows:

```
function getEventStream(type, target) {
    return function (k) {
        target.addEventListener(type, function listener(event) {
            target.removeEventListener(type, listener);
            k(cons(event, getEventStream(type, target)));
        });
    };
}
```

Unfortunately now that we've made it asynchronous we'll need to create asynchronous versions of all the functions that operate on lazy lists as well (e.g. `take`). Not only are we now stuck in a callback hell but we also need two versions of each function: synchronous and asynchronous.

How would you resolve this problem? Is there any other way to create lazy event streams in JavaScript? BTW I already created a gist for event streams in JavaScript using the subscription model: https://gist.github.com/aaditmshah/8381875

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for promises, which are perfect for representing both synchronously and asynchronously available values.

A stream would then be a promise for a structure that contains the head, and a promise for the tail. You might want to have a look at my demo implementation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414193/1048572.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some research into streams in JavaScript last year:

[What's the relationship between streamjs and linqjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630368/whats-the-relationship-between-streamjs-and-linqjs)

I ended up reverse engineering streamjs and extending it for my purposes.